# How to wait for a specified number of elements in Selenium (C#)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need a method, which waits for a given number of elements. For example when i use a Search Filter, i want to check after results are displayed, if there is really just x result.

There are just a few answers to a similar question, but they don't work for me.

```
public void WaitForGivenNumberOfElements(string selector, int i) {
   Wait until given i of selector are displayed <<
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details on what exactly you are looking for. Are you trying to wait for X number of elements or after elements are displayed, assert that an expected element exists in the list, etc. Add a practical example and the expectations along with your current code attempts in a [mcve]. Also add relevant HTML, properly formatted.

Comment: Practical example: Ive got a table with several rows (XPATH: '//table//*[@class='mud-table-row']'. ). I send a string to the SearchTextField, and get a result of x rows. Now the next step is, to wait for the given x number of rows (The XPATH above). For this i need a method, which waits for max 5 seconds until i throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method like below ,using a Fluent wait which will also timeout in case the count never equals expected

```
 public void waitUntilElementCountIs(IWebDriver driver, By by, int expectedCount)
    {
        DefaultWait<IWebDriver> fluentWait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
        fluentWait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        fluentWait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
        fluentWait.Until(d => d.FindElements(by).Count == expectedCount);   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot =) Solved also some other timing issues :D Is there also a way, to include the check for "int expectedCount = 0"? It seems to load endlessly